# .NET Compact Framework 3.5 on Windows Mobile 2003 SE

Tags: compact-framework

Does .NET Compact Framework 3.5 work on Windows Mobile 2003 SE without limitations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it works fine.  The [documentation for the download](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e3821449-3c6b-42f1-9fd9-0041345b3385&displaylang=en) shows this as well.

Comment: Why then Sync Framework 1.0 for devices, written in .NET 3.5, doesn't work on Windows Mobile 2003 ?

Comment: Becasue it uses pieces that are specific to, and available only on later devices.  The CF is compatible with older devices, but the sync framework is not due to dependencies.  It's similar to the fact that the CF can use the Microsoft.WindowsMobile namespace if you're targeting a later model device.